# delete column in DataGrid in an MVVM environment

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am attempting to delete an entire column from a DataGrid. My DataGrid Itemsource is bound to a Datatable. When I delete the column from the DataTable, the contents of the rows in the DataGrid disappear, but the header stays as well as the empty boxes.

I tried adding a DataGrid in my viewmodel and binding the dataGrid to that, but it did not seem to have any effect and my code got pretty ugly. I was able to add a button to delete it in code behind using:

```
TestDG.Columns.RemoveAt(idNum);
```

But this didn't seem like the correct approach, and I would like it tied to the view model for error checking etc. It seems like the DataTable and DataGrid could get out of sync deleting in 2 different spots.

My Xaml for the Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DTLines}" CanUserAddRows="False" ColumnWidth="*">            
    </DataGrid>
```

My code in my view model

```
...
    public DataTable DTLines
    {
        get
        {
            return testDT;
        }
        set
        {
            testDT = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DTLines");
        }
    } 
...
    private void ExecuteCloseLang()
    {
        TestDT.Columns.Remove("German");
        // What do I put here to remove the line?
    }
```

If you need anything else to clarify please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you can try setting column's `Visibility` to `Collapsed`.

Comment: can you use like an ObservableCollection instead of a datatable? and bind to that

Comment: I tried the ObservableCollection, Unfortunately the end result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

A view model shouldn't know anything about some columns in a `DataGrid` in a view. It is the view or the control itself that should be responsible for adding or removing columns from the `DataGrid`.

So your view model should probably notify the view when a column is removed from the `DataTable` and the view should then delete the column from the `DataGrid` in response to this action. This is proabably sort of what you are currently doing I guess.

Don't try to reference the `DataGrid` itself from the view model. Raise an event when the `DataTable` is modified and handle this event in the view.

Comment: I believe I follow what you mean. Since this is a view issue, it should be handled where the view is. I thought by removing the column in the DataTable, the DataGrid would also update, which it does, but it leaves the empty column. How would I tell the DataGrid to rebuild itself, or remove the column?